# HK2 Injection With Circular Dependency

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

I am using HK2 as dependency injection framework. I am instantiating a State Machine inside my application. So, A <-> B is quite possible because depending on the input, one can transition back to A from B.

```
@Singleton 
class StateManager extends SomeInterface{

    @Inject
    private B b;

    @Inject
    private A a;
}

@Singleton 
class A extends State{

    @Inject
    private B b;

    @Inject
    private StateManager sm;

}

@Singleton 
class B extends State{

    @Inject
    private A a;

    @Inject
    private StateManager sm;
}
```

How can I achieve something like this? Above example is just for illustration. I have more states than this. I tried to see if it is a duplicate but couldn't find one that deals with. When I try to `ServiceLocator.getService(StateManager.class)`to get this graph, I get circular dependency exception. What is the better of doing such things?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to to inject [`javax.inject.Provider<B>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html). From the Javadoc

> Provides instances of `T`. Typically implemented by an injector. For any type `T` that can be injected, you can also inject `Provider<T>`. Compared to injecting `T` directly, injecting `Provider<T>` enables:
>
> - retrieving multiple instances.
> - lazy or optional retrieval of an instance.
> - **breaking circular dependencies.**
> - abstracting scope so you can look up an instance in a smaller scope from an instance in a containing scope.

Then just call `get()` when you need it

```
B b = bProvider.get();
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid having Provider<T> in my domain model. But, if it cannot be avoided then so be it. However, even after doing this. I added PostConstruct method to get actual instances by calling `aProvider.get()`. The issue is that I also added `PostConstruct` in A where I do `smProvider.get()` and it again goes into circular dependency. It seems only way to break this by having setters, which I have so far been trying to avoid.

Comment: When you use a Provider you often cannot do the get in the PostConstruct, since that would cause the cycle to be there again.  HK2 guarantees that before anything is injected into anything else (or looked up) that the instance has been *fully* initialized, which includes calling the PostConstruct (with exceptions for proxies).